# detecting two keyboard buttons in javascript

Tags: javascript

im writing a simple canvas game and want to be able to move my character diagonally on the screen. how do I detect two keys pressed say up and right? 
heres my code so far-

```
function keyHit(evt){
switch (evt.keyCode) {
case 38:  /* Up arrow was pressed */
if (player2y >= 1){
player2y -= 4;
 } else {player2y = 0;}
break;
case 40:  /* Down arrow was pressed */
if (player2y <= 364){
player2y += 4;
} else { player2y = 365;}
break;
case 37:  /* Left arrow was pressed */
if (player2x >= 1){
player2x -= 4;
} else {player2x = 0;}
break;
case 39:  /* Right arrow was pressed */
if (player2x <= 665){
player2x += 4;
} else {player2x = 666;}
break;
}
}
```

Comment: Read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14087726/645956) - different language, but same idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trap "keydown" and "keyup" events and maintain the list of keys that are currently pressed. Example:

```js
pressed = {}


window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  pressed[e.keyCode] = 1
  handler(Object.keys(pressed).sort())
}

window.onkeyup = function(e) {
  delete pressed[e.keyCode];
  handler(Object.keys(pressed).sort())
}

function handler(pressed) {
  document.getElementById("log").value = pressed
  if(pressed == "38,39")
    alert("Up+Right pressed!")
}
```

```html
<textarea id="log"></textarea><br>click here first, then press some keys
```

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys, first set of examples claims sort() isn't necessary?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: object iteration order is not well-defined, I prefer to sort just in case.