# How do I move an image smoothly after clicking in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, frame-rate

I have decided to make my game in pygame instead, and here is what I have coded so far:

```py
from typing import Tuple
import pygame
from PIL import ImageGrab

# finding the height of the screen by taking a screenshot.
img = ImageGrab.grab()
(WIDTH, HEIGHT) = (img.size)

x = WIDTH / 2 - 470
y = HEIGHT / 2 - 400

fistx1 = x - 80
fistx2 = fistx1;

fisty1 = y + 40

fisty2 = y - 50
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

RESOLUTION = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)

BACKGROUND_COLOR: Tuple[int, int, int] = (79, 205, 109)

MOVESPEED = 5

# window stuff
window = pygame.display.set_mode(RESOLUTION, flags=pygame.RESIZABLE, depth=32)
pygame.display.set_caption("The Connection")
window.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)

running = True

# all images for the game here
player_image = pygame.image.load("Connector.png")
player_fist1_image = pygame.image.load("Connector_hand.png")
player_fist2_image = player_fist1_image

while running:
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    clicked = pygame.mouse.get_pressed();
    class Player():
        def __init__(self, hp, image, fist1image, fist2image):
            global fisty1, fistx1, fisty2
            self.hp = hp
            self.image = image
            self.fist1image = fist1image
            self.fist2image = fist2image

            window.blit(self.image, (x, y))
            window.blit(self.fist1image, (fistx1, fisty1))
            window.blit(self.fist2image, (fistx2, fisty2))

        def move(self, movespeed):
            global x, y, fistx1, fisty1, fisty2
            if pressed[pygame.K_a]:
                x -= movespeed
                fistx1 -= movespeed
            elif pressed[pygame.K_d]:
                x += movespeed
                fistx1 += movespeed
            elif pressed[pygame.K_w]:
                y -= movespeed
                fisty1 -= movespeed
                fisty2 -= movespeed
            elif pressed[pygame.K_s]:
                y += movespeed
                fisty1 += movespeed
                fisty2 += movespeed

        def deal_damage(self, damage):
            global x, y, fistx1, fisty1
            fistx1 -= 25
            window.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
            window.blit(self.fist1image, (fistx1, fisty1));
            pygame.display.flip();

    # this is the function we use to actually call it. This is more helpful and less confusing for an idiot like me
    def actual_deal():
        main_player.deal_damage(25);


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            try:
                pygame.quit()
            except pygame.error:
                pass
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                actual_deal();

    window.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)

    main_player = Player(100, player_image, fist1image=player_fist1_image, fist2image=player_fist2_image)
    main_player.move(movespeed=MOVESPEED)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60);
```

For context, the fist's have to go forward and then backward. However, the fists aren't moving smoothly, which has two problems:

1. It doesn't look good. I want to show this to other people, so I want it to look good.
2. When I retract the fists, it doesn't look like they moved forward in the first place. I'd have to add `time.sleep` in between, but I am not willing to do that.

Here is the output I am getting when I punch:
<sub>Placed in a spoiler so it isn't intrusive</sub>

> [image]

As you can see, it moves in a blocky fashion. If you want to see the output I desire, then move the character around with the WASD keys and see how smoothly the characters move. I want the same thing for the fists.

If it matters, I am using pycharm to code this, and I'm running it from Command Prompt. I also have Windows 10.

Lastly, I have tried changing the framerate by doing this:

Here are the questions I have already looked at:

```py
clock.tick(360);
```

But to no avail.

I have looked at these questions:

---

[smooth movement in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477736/smooth-movement-in-pygame)

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48227/smooth-movement-pygame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of this I can spot. Firstly, function and class definitions are supposed to be outside of main loop because defining the same thing over and over again in a loop doesn't make any sense. Second you are calling `pygame.display.flip` twice, which is not needed. Flip should only be called once, otherwise it causes flickering. Third, you are drawing in `__init__` method and creating a new instance every frame. Usually, an instance is only made once, and there are methods of that instance to do something with that instance. So, instead of drawing in the `__init__`, make a new method called draw.

Now to answer your question, it moves in blocks becasue:

1. You are moving it 25 frames at once, so it skips 25 pixel at once and draws again in the new position.
2. You are using `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`. This function only returns once true per click. So if you hold down  your mouse button, it wouldn't work because it returns `True` in the first frame and `None` after that. To continuously update the mouse state, you need to use `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`.

New code with everything I mentioned above implemented (NOTE: I changed images to surfaces to make it work, so you might wanna change it to image again):

```
from typing import Tuple
import pygame
from PIL import ImageGrab

# finding the height of the screen by taking a screenshot.
img = ImageGrab.grab()
(WIDTH, HEIGHT) = (img.size)

x = WIDTH / 2 - 470
y = HEIGHT / 2 - 400

fistx1 = x - 80
fistx2 = fistx1;

fisty1 = y + 40

fisty2 = y - 50
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

RESOLUTION = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)

BACKGROUND_COLOR: Tuple[int, int, int] = (79, 205, 109)

MOVESPEED = 5

# window stuff
window = pygame.display.set_mode(RESOLUTION, flags=pygame.RESIZABLE, depth=32)
pygame.display.set_caption("The Connection")
window.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)

running = True

# all images for the game here
player_image = pygame.Surface((50, 50)).convert()
player_fist1_image = pygame.Surface((10, 10)).convert()
player_fist2_image = player_fist1_image

class Player():
    def __init__(self, hp, image, fist1image, fist2image):
        global fisty1, fistx1, fisty2
        self.hp = hp
        self.image = image
        self.fist1image = fist1image
        self.fist2image = fist2image

    def move(self, movespeed):
        global x, y, fistx1, fisty1, fisty2
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]:
            x -= movespeed
            fistx1 -= movespeed
        elif pressed[pygame.K_d]:
            x += movespeed
            fistx1 += movespeed
        elif pressed[pygame.K_w]:
            y -= movespeed
            fisty1 -= movespeed
            fisty2 -= movespeed
        elif pressed[pygame.K_s]:
            y += movespeed
            fisty1 += movespeed
            fisty2 += movespeed

    def draw(self):
        window.blit(self.image, (x, y))
        window.blit(self.fist1image, (fistx1, fisty1))
        window.blit(self.fist2image, (fistx2, fisty2))

    def deal_damage(self, damage):
        global x, y, fistx1, fisty1
        mousePressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if mousePressed[0]:
            fistx1 -= 1
        window.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        window.blit(self.fist1image, (fistx1, fisty1));
        #pygame.display.flip();

main_player = Player(100, player_image, fist1image=player_fist1_image, fist2image=player_fist2_image)

# this is the function we use to actually call it. This is more helpful and less confusing for an idiot like me
def actual_deal():
    main_player.deal_damage(25);

while running:
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    clicked = pygame.mouse.get_pressed();

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            try:
                pygame.quit()
            except pygame.error:
                pass

    window.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    main_player.move(movespeed=MOVESPEED)
    main_player.deal_damage(50)
    main_player.draw()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60);
```

Edit: Forgot to mention this but you are taking `damage` argument in  `deal_damage` method but not using it.

Comment: But one question: How can I make it so that when I click the mouse button for say, a millisecond, the fist object moves the same distance? I don't want it to go while I am holding the mouse button, if you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: Which one is the fist object. And it moves same distance as ?

Comment: If you don't want it to keep moving then you can use pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN but that would defeat the purpose of the answer.

Comment: I have actually figured it out. I just had it move really far when I click, and then when you release the mouse button it brings it back in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

To add onto @hippozhipos answer. A big benefit from using a `class` is you don't need to use `global` variables. You just set them as attributes.

You are also attempting to quit within your game loop.
If `running` is `False` it will exit your game loop and quit on it's own.

There is also no need to fill outside your loop since it is filled every frame.

I included a minimal working example of how that can be achieved.

```
import pygame
from PIL import ImageGrab

class Player():
    def __init__(self, img, x, y, window):
        self.fist = img
        self.pos = (x - 80, y + 40)
        self.win = window

    def move(self, movespeed, pressed):
        # here we maintain the players position with self.pos
        # this allows you to have multiple instances
        # with different positions
        x, y = self.pos
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]:
            x -= movespeed
        elif pressed[pygame.K_d]:
            x += movespeed
        elif pressed[pygame.K_w]:
            y -= movespeed
        elif pressed[pygame.K_s]:
            y += movespeed

        self.pos = (x, y)
    
    def display(self):
        self.win.blit(self.fist, self.pos)

pygame.init()
screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = screenshot.size
RESOLUTION = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
BACKGROUND_COLOR = (79, 205, 109)
MOVESPEED = 5

window = pygame.display.set_mode(RESOLUTION, flags=pygame.RESIZABLE, depth=32)
pygame.display.set_caption("The Connection")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# this is whatever your image is
img = pygame.image.load('fist.png')
x = int(WIDTH / 2 - 470)
y = int(HEIGHT / 2 - 400)
main_player = Player(img=img, x=x, y=y, window=window)

running = True
while running:
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    main_player.move(movespeed=MOVESPEED, pressed=pressed)

    window.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    main_player.display()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```